# PHP - Replace everything between String including content

Tags: php, string, web, replace

I want to iterate over a string which looks like this.

`Booo ahh [Hello] and what is [Baby] at your [Mouse]`

My target is to replace every `[@@@]` with another string, which is not static, but can handle the content between the brackets.

Should be something like

```
function replace_string($text) {
 ...
 //Maybe some kind of loop for all brackets
 {
  $content = ... //For example Hello, Baby, Mouse => @@@
  $replacement = "I'm a " . $content . "!";
  ...
 }
 return $replacedString;
}
```

I don't think it can work like in my "suggestion", but I hope I could show what I want to do and somebody can help me.

Comment: Have you looked at regexs yet? Are the terms static or anything between `[]` should be replaced? https://regex101.com/r/wxsGeN/2/

Comment: How do you determine what it is being replaced by? Is it always the same for whatever word is in the brackets?

Comment: I want to use whatever in the brackets is in my new string (for each bracket) - I don't want to use a static string instead

Comment: That is easier, look at the example i provided and do some research on regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i understand, you want to have this string at the end:

> Booo ahh [I'm a Hello!] and what is [I'm a Baby!] at your [I'm a Mouse!]

So you can use preg_replace function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Your code will looks like:

```
function replace_string($text) 
{     
   return preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]+/', "[I'm a $1!]", $string);
}
```

so

```
<?php

$string = 'Booo ahh [Hello] and what is [Baby] at your [Mouse]';
echo replace_string($string);
// will display 
// Booo ahh [I'm a Hello!] and what is [I'm a Baby!] at your [I'm a Mouse!]
```

not sure if you want to keep the brackets or not, if you don't, and want to have

> Booo ahh I'm a Hello! and what is I'm a Baby! at your I'm a Mouse!

just use:

```
preg_replace('/\[([^\]]+)\]+/', "I'm a $1!", $string);
```

You can see the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/8hJQr0/1